# adding a new column to a data frame with X Y coordinates, classifying them according to fixed locations

Tags: python-3.x, distance

I have a dataframe with X Y coordinates and another dataframe with fixed locations and would like to add a new column in the first data frame that classifies the X Y coordinates based in the minimum distance to the fixed locations (n=10).

I tried to loop through the first data frame and I need another embedded for loop that compares the X Y coordinates with the fixed locations (for example a1= 200,180). Based on the minimum distance, the X Y coordinates should be classified according to location. How to do?

df1[:10]

```
     X    Y
```

0      224  234
1      258  232
2      225  235
3      257  232
4      226  235
5      257  232
6      226  235
7      257  232
8      224  234
9      258  232

df2 (fixed location)
seats = [[260, 165], [315, 165], [370, 165], [423, 165], [485, 200], [420, 240] , [370, 240], [315, 240] ,[260, 240], [200,200]]

Based on min distances, a new column should be added to the first dataframe classifying the data points according to seats0-10.

Comment: the first dataframe contains XY columns and should be compared to the XY columns of the fixed locations (a1-10).

Comment: could you share codes, what did you try till now ? Plus the structure of your dataframe, plus distance function that you are referring to

Comment: There is nothing really to show since I havent found the right way to do. I looked into cdist so far but shouldnt it basically be the difference between the two coordinate pairs? The logic seems clear to me, just my python capability seems to hold me back. I added an example of the first data frame (first 10 rows) that have to be compared to all 10 fixed locations(seats). The closest fixed location to the data point should then be added in the new column. I deeply appreciate your help.

Comment: I was thinking of working with centroids, so clustering the data points first and use the centroids of those clusters to compare to the fixed locations. Does any of this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
minDist = []
for i in range(df1.shape[0]):
   dist_list = []
   for f in range(df2.shape[0]):
      dist = np.linalg.norm(df1.iloc[i,:]-df2[f,:])
      dist_list.append(dist)
   minDist.append(dist_list.index(min(dist_list)))
df1['distance'] = minDist
```

Comment: Thank you so much Rishoban!! Just one minor thing. When you compare the two, df1.iloc[i,:]-df2[f,:]), i get the error: TypeError: '(5, slice(None, None, None))' is an invalid key. Why dont you use iloc in df2 as well, what is going wrong with comparing the df1 observation with all the 10 seats observations? i deeply appreciate your help.

Comment: Sorry for mistake in the second for loop i mistakenly add another variable. Now i changed it. Actually that is df2. In this code df2 is ndarray not dataframe that's why iloc not used.

Comment: I deeply appreciate!! Works very well!